# JavaFX2: Detached toolbar

Tags: javafx-2, toolbar

I have a javafx application showing an image(imagine paint from windows). The next step is to create a detached toolbar that the user can move around on the application. I am able to create a stationary toolbar and do the normal operations that I would do on the application.

Any pointers would be helpful.

Regards

Comment: Download and adapt the [Draggable Panels Example](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/events/filters.htm) from Oracle.

Comment: Take a look at TiwulFX DetachableTabPane. Hope it helps. Video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ULgSLgR12O0 .Source: https://bitbucket.org/panemu/tiwulfx/src/b4ae290b11591bc04274a9475fd113edfa06884f/src/main/java/com/panemu/tiwulfx/control/DetachableTabPane.java?at=master